# Why is the @JoinTable annotation is always present along with the @OneToMany annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

Consider a one-to-many association like project and task, where a project can have multiple tasks. If this is modeled using a foreign key clause in the task table which refers to the primary key of the project table, then we put the @JoinColumn annotation in the owning side i.e. the task table as the many side is always the owning side.
But if this is mapped by using a third table project_task, the @JoinTable annotation is being used on the inverse side i.e. on the project entity. But @JoinTable should always be on the owning side.

Approach one with foreign key:

```
@Entity
public class Project {

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
   private Collection<Task> tasks;

}

@Entity
public class Task {

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_ID")
   private Project project;

}
```

Approach two with third table and @JoinTable Annotation:

```
@Entity
public class Project {

    @JoinTable(name = "MY_JT",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "PROJECT_ID",
    ),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "TASK_ID"
    )
    @OneToMany
    private List<Task> tasks;

}
@Entity
    public class Task {

       private Project project;

}
```

Why is the owning side shifted to the project entity when using @JoinTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to understand owning side as the entity which knows of the other end of the association.

I am the **owning entity** if i'm **able to reach the associated entity** so i have informations which allow me to reach the associated entity.

The most used case is to put the foreign key on the many side of the association.
So if you have a relation between Project and Task and we 're telling that 1 Project can have many Tasks.
A project_id column will be add on Task table which will be the owning side of the relation because it held information (Project Fk) which allow it to reach Project Entity from Car.

When you're using @Jointable on OneToMany association you're designing a **unidirectional association** so car entity don't have anymore the information to reach associated User entity like in a bidirectional association.
This information is now kept by a join table which is in User entity so User entity become the owning side of the relation.

So to answer your question the owning side shifted to Projet because now you can't anymore reach a project from a task and the only way to have tasks associated to a project is to use the join table held by Project entity. So now It's project entity through its joinTable wich keep informations to retrieve the tasks associated to a project.
Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'shifted'? The owning side of an association is either the *only* side of that association, or the side whose association annotation does not have the `mappedBy` parameter present.

In your second example, `Project` is the owning side, because the association is unidirectional (there is no mapping of that association in `Task`).

The owning side of a association is the one that manages the association (i.e. changes to that side will be recorded). Had `Task` been defined like this:

```
@Entity
public class Task {
   @ManyToOne(mappedBy="tasks")
   private Project project;
}
```

`Project` would still be the owning side (meaning: changes to `Project.tasks` would be recorded, while changes to `Task.project` would be ignored). This is an unusual, yet valid mapping (it typically makes more sense to declare the many side the owning side in a bidirectional one-to-many association, but doing the opposite is also permitted).